# addition and multiplication table for factor ring of $Z_2\bigoplus Z_3/\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

For $\mathbb Z_2\bigoplus \mathbb Z_3$, define $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$ and $(a,b)(c,d)=(ac,bd)$ with $a+c$ and $ac$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $b+d$ and $bd$ in $\mathbb Z_3$. Write addition and multiplication tables for factor ring $\mathbb Z_2\bigoplus \mathbb Z_3 $/$\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$.

I'm not sure about the factor ring, should it be$ \{((0,0)+\{(0,0),(1,0)\}, (0,1)+\{(0,0),(1,0)\},\cdots,(1,2)+\{(0,0),(1,0)\})\}$? But then how should I proceed and simplify it?

Comment: I suppose that $\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$ denotes the subgroup generated by  $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I think so

Comment: Well the subgroup is generated by $(1,0)$ alone, and is just $\mathbf Z_2\times\{0\}$, so the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z_3$.

Comment: @Bernard  Sorry I don't quite get it, can you be more specific?

Comment: $(\mathbf Z_2\times\mathbf Z_3)/(\mathbf Z_2\times\{0\})\simeq(\mathbf Z_2/\mathbf Z_2)\times(\mathbf Z_3/\{0\})\simeq\{0\}\times\mathbf Z_3\simeq\mathbf Z_3$. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Bernard But how would this help me write the addition and multiplication table, I thought I need to at least write all the elements in Z2⨁Z3Z2⨁Z3 /{(0,0),(1,0)} to start

Comment: You just have to write representatives of each class. There are only $3$ classes: $(0_2,0_3)$,  $(0_2,1_3)$,   $(0_2,2_3)$

Comment: @Bernard I don't recognize this format, what does each of them stand for?

Comment: The indices refer to the modulus of each factor – they're not really necessary, it is only to be perfectly clear about which ring it belongs to.

Comment: @Barnard Can you write them as direct products so I can have a clearer sense?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I wrote pairs, which are elements  of a direct product. The class   $\overline{(0_2,1_3)}$, say, consists of the two vectors $\{(0_2,1_3),(1_2,1_3)\}$. Both pairs are elements of $\mathbf Z_2\times\mathbf Z_3$.

Comment: @Bernard I'm just not familiar with the notation $\{(0_2,1_3),(1_2,1_3)\}$, are they the same with {(0,1),(1,1)}?

Comment: Absolutely. I only specify  which field they belong to.